# K8S: Routing with Istio return 404

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I'm new in the k8s world.

Im my dev enviroment, I use ngnix as proxy(with CORS configs and with headers forwarding like ) for the different microservices (all made with spring boot) I have. In a k8s cluster, I had to replace it with Istio?

I'm trying to run a simple microservice(for now) and use Istio for routing to it. I've installed istio with google cloud.

If I navigate to IstioIP/auth/api/v1 it returns 404

This is my yaml file

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
    - port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - '*'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /auth
    route:
    - destination:
        host: auth-srv
        port:
          number: 8082
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
  labels:
    app: auth-srv
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8082
  selector:
    app: auth-srv
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-srv
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-srv
          image: gcr.io/{{MY_PROJECT_ID}}/auth-srv:1.5
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: '-DZIPKIN_SERVER=http://zipkin:9411'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8082
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/v1
              port: 8082
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: does it say "default backend - 404" ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like istio doesn't know anything about the url. Therefore you are getting a 404 error response.
If you look  closer at the configuration in the virtual server you have configured istio to match on path `/auth`.

So if you try to request `ISTIOIP/auth` you will reach your microservice application. Here is image to describe the traffic flow and why you are getting a 404 response.

[image: Logic of the routing]

Comment: since I'm not receiving responses to my question, I switch to nginx ingress and now it works successfully. Thanks for the support

Comment: @Fidelis you can check the istio cert, if it is correct or not.